# infinite series expansion and rational functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

Consider the following function
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k.$$

Let us say I know $a_k$ belongs to a strict subset $F\subset\mathbb{R}$.

I want to characterize the set of sequences $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ for which $f(x)$ is a rational function in $x$.

Can someone point me to relevant results in literature?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I mean the function $f(x)$ is a rational function. I have updated the question now! thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

As

$$f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)},$$ past a certain degree the coefficients of $f(x)q(x)$ vanish.

Hence except for the first few, the $a_k$ are constrained by a linear recurrence on $\text{deg}(q)+1$ terms.